# get more significant points from array

Tags: python, arrays, compression

I need to compress a numpy array by getting the more significant points , I mean where there is a change , but it has to be a specific number of points , for example my array may be 100 values i will need the 40 most meaningful ones.
I tried the rdp algorithme but you cant specify the number of points , you cant expect the lenght of the results
so for now i doing this but it is just random points not the most important

```
n=40   
indices = np.linspace(0, len(array) - 1, num=n)
```

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Do you want to find points that are "important" so that you can investigate what's going on at that point? Or do you just want to compress the representation so that you can reproduce a similar curve with a fixed number of data points?

Comment: my goal is to compress the data without loosing the shape to be able to reproduce it later as you said

Comment: Maybe a [B-Spline fiŧ](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.make_lsq_spline.html#scipy.interpolate.make_lsq_spline) helps. You can control the number of knots to have a fixed size and you can save and restore the [Bspline object](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.BSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.BSpline) via its `t, c, k` attributes and constructor. But it would provide uniform smoothing rather than focus on regions with large dynamic

Comment: alternative idea: 1. Split point list in two as per RDP, compute the `dmax` parameter for each. 2. Organize the two sub-lists into a [binary heap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html?highlight=heap#module-heapq) sorted by the `dmax`. 3. Remove the segment with the largest `dmax` from the heap. 4. Split it as per one recursion of RDP. 5. Put the two new segments back into the heap. 6. Repeat from points 3 onwards until you reach your desired number of points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation of the idea I outlined in my comments. What we do is this: We use the regular [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm&oldid=1181177480). But instead of recursively splitting the point lists until an epsilon is achieved, we always split the worst sub-list until we reach the target size in remaining points.

The basic idea seems to work. The base algorithm is lifted from Wikipedia for validation and comparison.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import heapq
import math

import numpy as np


def perpendicular_distance(point, start, end):
    """Distance from point to the line through start and end"""
    dist = end - start
    absdist = np.linalg.norm(dist)
    if absdist == 0.:
        return np.linalg.norm(point - start)
    return np.linalg.norm(np.cross(dist, start - point)) / absdist


def douglas_peucker(pointlist, epsilon):
    if len(pointlist) < 3:
        return list(pointlist)
    # Find the point with the maximum distance
    start, end = pointlist[0], pointlist[-1]
    dmax, index = max((perpendicular_distance(point, start, end), index)
                      for index, point in enumerate(pointlist))
    if dmax < epsilon:
        return [start, end]
    rtrn = douglas_peucker(pointlist[:index + 1], epsilon)
    # careful: The point at index is in both lists
    rtrn[-1:] = douglas_peucker(pointlist[index:], epsilon)
    return rtrn


def perpendicular_distance_vectorized(pointlist, start, end):
    offsets = start - pointlist
    dist = end - start
    absdist = np.linalg.norm(dist)
    scale = np.divide(1., absdist)
    if not math.isfinite(scale):
        return np.linalg.norm(offsets, axis=1)
    cross = np.cross(dist, offsets)
    cross = np.linalg.norm(cross, axis=1) if cross.ndim > 1 else abs(cross)
    return cross * scale


class DprList:
    def __init__(self, pointlist, startindex):
        self.pointlist = pointlist
        self.startindex = startindex
        if len(pointlist) < 3:
            self.index = 0
            self.dmax = 0.
            return
        start, end = pointlist[0], pointlist[-1]
        distances = perpendicular_distance_vectorized(
                pointlist[1:-1], start, end)
        index = np.argmax(distances)
        self.dmax = distances[index]
        self.index = index + 1

    @property
    def start(self):
        return self.pointlist[0]

    @property
    def end(self):
        return self.pointlist[-1]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.pointlist)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        """Higher dmax results in lower sort order

        Required for python's heapq module
        """
        return self.dmax > other.dmax

    def split(self):
        pointlist = self.pointlist
        index = self.index
        startindex = self.startindex
        front = DprList(pointlist[:index + 1], startindex)
        back = DprList(pointlist[index:], startindex + index)
        return front, back


def douglas_peucker_heap(pointlist, targetcount):
    if len(pointlist) <= targetcount:
        return list(pointlist)
    heap = [DprList(pointlist, 0)]
    finished = [] # sublists with length 2
    for _ in range(targetcount - 2):
        worst = heapq.heappop(heap)
        for sublist in worst.split():
            if len(sublist) < 3:
                finished.append(sublist)
            else:
                heapq.heappush(heap, sublist)
    heap += finished
    heap.sort(key=lambda sublist: sublist.startindex)
    rtrn = [heap[0].start]
    rtrn.extend(sublist.end for sublist in heap)
    return rtrn


def test():
    points = np.array(
        ((0., 0.),
         (1., 2.),
         (3., -2.),
         (4., -2.),
         (5., -3.),
         (6., 5.),
         (7., 7.),
         (8., 0.)))
    print(np.asarray(douglas_peucker(points, 5.)))
    print(np.asarray(douglas_peucker_heap(points, 4)))


def bench():
    import sys
    points = np.empty((1000, 2))
    points[:, 0] = np.arange(len(points))
    points[:, 1] = np.random.default_rng([1]).random(len(points))
    if sys.argv[1] == "base":
        for _ in range(10):
            np.asarray(douglas_peucker(points, 0.87))
        print(len(np.asarray(douglas_peucker(points, 0.87))))
    else:
        for _ in range(1000):
            np.asarray(douglas_peucker_heap(points, 54))
        print(len(np.asarray(douglas_peucker_heap(points, 54))))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # test()
    bench()
```

### Bonus

For completeness and to make the benchmark more even, here is a version of the standard algorithm that is vectorized and avoids Python's recursion limit. It effectively has the same speed as the heap based version. For very large point lists I expect it to be slightly faster since it has better locality of data when iterating over the sub-lists.

```py
def douglas_peucker_optimized(pointlist, epsilon):
    if len(pointlist) < 3 or not epsilon > 0.:
        return list(pointlist)
    rtrn = [pointlist[0]]
    stack = [DprList(pointlist, 0)]
    while stack:
        sublist = stack.pop()
        if sublist.dmax < epsilon:
            rtrn.append(sublist.end)
            continue
        front, back = sublist.split()
        stack += [back, front]
    return rtrn
```

Comment: thank you that is what i needed it is just a bit time consuming so im trying to find a technique that may be faster

Comment: @user3379546 I'm pretty sure that splitting is done slightly wrong and I plan to fix that. Also, for performance, finding the index can be properly vectorized with numpy. I didn't do that for simplicity

Comment: @user3379546 I've fixed and accelerated the code

Comment: yes it is much faster now thank you